# Prevent body's onclick function inside div?

Tags: javascript, onclick

```
<body>
    <div>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
    window.onclick = function() {do something;}
</script>
```

How do I prevent clicks inside of the div from carrying out the body's onclick function?

Comment: return false at the end of your div click function

Comment: preventDefault stopPropagation

Comment: That's some weird css :)

Comment: Your HTML structure is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Try substituting `<script>` element for `<style>` element , utilizing `e.target.tagName` to determine if clicked element is `DIV` , return `false` if clicked element is `DIV` , else log clicked element to `console`

```css
div {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 border: 2px dotted tomato;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div>
      click
    </div>
</body>
<script>
    window.onclick = function(e) {
      if (e.target.tagName === "DIV") return false
      // do something;
      else console.log(this)
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Will this work if there are child elements within the div and you click on them?

Comment: @torazaburo _"Will this work if there are child elements within the div and you click on them? "_ Good point. Did not attempt with child elements ; would not return same result utilizing `e.target.tagName === "DIV"` as condition. Minimal `html` at Question did not contain child elements , no feedback from OP ,  yet , as to application details

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to support modern browsers (>=IE11), use `pointer-events`:

```
div { pointer-events: none; }
```

Note that this will also inhibit all kinds of mouse-related effects, including hover.